# How to delete chat messages from XMPP server in android?

Tags: android, xmpp, chat

Now i am doing chat application. I am using XMPP for chat. I am able to do chat. Now I want to delete chat message in my chat message list like a whats app. That message will delete also in server. I tired by getPacketID(). But i can't be achieve. How can I delete the particluar chat message from server by pro grammatically in android? Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am searching this for an ios